# How can I begin to develop EDI 837 Professional?

Tags: vb.net, biztalk, edi

I want to develop an **EDI 837** Professional project and I don't understand from where to start. If anybody knows about this &  have worked on it then please help me & give me advice where  do I start from ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what you are trying to do. I am new to this as well and I am trying to generate EDI X12 837 files from a datasource in our system. I have found [this](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/) open source project to be very helpful. It contains an executable that can transform EDI's to XML. There are also some API's that you can use if you are developing in C#/VB.

Also you can take a look at [this article](http://www.xtranslator.com/prod/beginguidex12.pdf). It provides information about EDI formatting. I found it very helpful in getting started.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a Web API that takes care of your 837P (and other) claims that can easily be integrated into your web based platform, check out https://837-edi.clearehr.com - it is free and eliminates a large amount of development (and costs, and headaches) for those trying to implement EDI insurance claims into their solutions. Over 1,000 payers supported at this point and more are added all the time.

Disclaimer: I am a developer at ClearEHR

Comment: the link provided in this answer is broken? Do we have an updated one ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is to get the 837 implementation guide.  It tells you what data goes into the file and how it should be structured.  The publisher of these documents is called wpc-edi.com.

The second thing you need is a good EDI library component that helps you create these files without having to worry about the format and just concentrate on the data.  One good one is RDPCrystal.com

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is using Microsoft BizTalk Server.Microsoft's BizTalk offers many added features for maintaining and monitoring the solution.

Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/edi-support-in-biztalk-server1 for details

Answer (score 0):

`EDI` or `IDOC` or `X12`, best practice in developing complex Integration solutions is to use canonical schemas.

This is a design pattern to decouple systems. Specially when you want this to expose as data contracts on your web services. For your `EDI 837` (Patient Info), Canonical schema might contain some additional info that you can reuse later.

```
EDI Schema -> Canonical Schema (Patient Info) -> Target Schema
```

There's a good article on how to create canonical schemas. You can find it [here](https://lingenfelder.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/create-a-canonical-schema-%E2%80%93-step-by-step/).